# why is this MySQL query producing the wrong row numbers?

Tags: mysql

given the following query

```
SET @num :=0, @current_shop_id := NULL, @current_product_id := NULL;

SELECT * FROM (

SELECT products.shop_id, products.product_id, @num := IF(@current_shop_id=shops.shop_id, IF(@current_product_id=products.product_id,@num,@num+1),0) AS row_number, @current_shop_id := shops.shop_id AS shop_dummy, @current_product_id := products.product_id AS product_dummy

    FROM
    favorites fav1 INNER JOIN
    products ON
    fav1.product_id=products.product_id AND 
    fav1.current=1 AND
    fav1.closeted=1 AND 
    fav1.user_id=30  INNER JOIN

    shops ON
    shops.shop_id = products.shop_id

    ORDER BY shops.shop ASC, products.product_id DESC

) AS rowed_results WHERE rowed_results.row_number>=0 AND rowed_results.row_number<(20) AND shop_id=130
```

I am expecting row_number values of the form

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| shop_id | product_id | row_number | shop_dummy | product_dummy |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
|     130 |    1153746 |          0 |        130 |       1153746 |
|     130 |    1153736 |          1 |        130 |       1153736 |
|     130 |    1139944 |          2 |        130 |       1139944 |
|     130 |    1098296 |          3 |        130 |       1098296 |
|     130 |    1017455 |          4 |        130 |       1017455 |
|     130 |     551953 |          5 |        130 |        551953 |
|     130 |     551914 |          6 |        130 |        551914 |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

(ie, all unique product_id values associated with a given shop_id value get a unique row number, starting from 0). Instead, I am getting

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| shop_id | product_id | row_number | shop_dummy | product_dummy |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
|     130 |    1153746 |          1 |        130 |       1153746 |
|     130 |    1153736 |          0 |        130 |       1153736 |
|     130 |    1139944 |          0 |        130 |       1139944 |
|     130 |    1098296 |          0 |        130 |       1098296 |
|     130 |    1017455 |          0 |        130 |       1017455 |
|     130 |     551953 |          1 |        130 |        551953 |
|     130 |     551914 |          0 |        130 |        551914 |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Michael Berkowski's solution (use three queries, one for retrieving data, one for adding row numbers, one for limiting by row) works (syntax slightly changed):

```
SET @num :=0, @current_shop_id := NULL, @current_product_id := NULL;

#limit by row

SELECT * FROM (

    #add row

    SELECT limit_query.*, @num := IF(@current_shop_id=shop_id, IF(@current_product_id=product_id,@num,@num+1),0) AS row_number, @current_shop_id := shop_id AS shop_dummy, @current_product_id := product_id AS product_dummy FROM (

        #retrieve data

        SELECT row_query.* FROM (

            SELECT products.shop_id, products.product_id

            FROM
            favorites fav1 INNER JOIN
            products ON
            fav1.product_id=products.product_id AND 
            fav1.current=1 AND
            fav1.closeted=1 AND 
            fav1.user_id=30  INNER JOIN

            shops ON
            shops.shop_id = products.shop_id

        ) AS row_query ORDER BY shop_id ASC, product_id DESC

    ) AS limit_query

) AS rowed_results WHERE rowed_results.row_number>=0 AND rowed_results.row_number<(20) AND shop_id=130;
```

Purely as a matter of educational interest, I'm wondering why it is not possible to add the row numbers and limit by row number at the same time, as in the following (non-functional) example

```
SET @num :=0, @current_shop_id := NULL, @current_product_id := NULL;

#limit by row

SELECT rowed_results.*, @num := IF(@current_shop_id=shop_id, IF(@current_product_id=product_id,@num,@num+1),0) AS row_number, @current_shop_id := shop_id AS shop_dummy, @current_product_id := product_id AS product_dummy FROM (

    #retrieve data

    SELECT row_query.* FROM (

        SELECT products.shop_id, products.product_id

        FROM
        favorites fav1 INNER JOIN
        products ON
        fav1.product_id=products.product_id AND 
        fav1.current=1 AND
        fav1.closeted=1 AND 
        fav1.user_id=30  INNER JOIN

        shops ON
        shops.shop_id = products.shop_id

    ) AS row_query ORDER BY shop_id ASC, product_id DESC

) AS rowed_results WHERE row_number>=0 AND row_number<(20) AND shop_id=130;
```

Comment: I guess the fact that you are using `@num := ` in your select doesn't help

Comment: Why do you need this `IF` to calculate this `ro_number`? From the `row_number` values that you are expecting `@num := @num + 1` will give you the exact values that you are looking for.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal you are correct, given the example. this is a simplified version of a more complicated query in which it is possible for multiple rows to have the same product_id value, requiring the conditional (since only rows with unique product_id values should have unique row_number values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rows to increment, it should be as simple a matter as moving the `@num` calculation into the outer query.  And in that situation, the `@current_product_id` should not be needed as `@num` can increment directly.

```
SET @num :=0, @current_shop_id := NULL, @current_product_id := NULL;

SELECT 
  *,
  /* Perform the row increment in the outer query so it acts on the final rowset */
  @num := @num+1 AS row_number
FROM (
    SELECT products.shop_id, products.product_id, @current_shop_id := shops.shop_id AS shop_dummy, @current_product_id := products.product_id AS product_dummy

    FROM
    favorites fav1 INNER JOIN
    products ON
    fav1.product_id=products.product_id AND 
    fav1.current=1 AND
    fav1.closeted=1 AND 
    fav1.user_id=30  INNER JOIN

    shops ON
    shops.shop_id = products.shop_id

    ORDER BY shops.shop ASC, products.product_id DESC

) AS rowed_results 
WHERE
  rowed_results.row_number>=0
  AND rowed_results.row_number<(20)
  AND shop_id=130
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and appear to have gotten it working by moving the @num calculation, then limiting by row number with a third query. I wasn't able to get it to work without using a third query to limit by row number (see query added to main question), and I'm curious why that might be. My `product_id` values actually are not unique, so I believe it is necessary to retain `@current_product_id` in order to determine whether to increment the `row_number` value (as different rows with the same `product_id` value should have the same `row_number` value)

Comment: @jela `row_number` is not yet known at the time the `WHERE` clause is applied and I should have caught that.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic checks both shop ID and product ID. If they are the same, then the counter increments, otherwise it resets to zero. Although your resultset has all the same shop IDs, it has different product IDs.